# postgresql ignores sysem locale on installation

Tags: postgresql

before installing I'm checking locale:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

After that normal install with

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

And in installation logs:

```
Creating new cluster 9.3/main ...
  config /etc/postgresql/9.3/main
  data   /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main
  locale C
  port   5432
```

This gives me template0 and template1 created as SQL_ASCII encoding, I know i can delete cluster and initdb again with --locale, but this is not an option for me as long I'm using chef recipe to init VM.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that I had no /etc/default/locale, so ran

```
update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

and now it installs correctly